# How do I install psycopg2 in a virtualenv that seems to not have gcc access?

Tags: python, virtualenv, psycopg2

I'm trying to install psycopg2 in a virtualenv but it seems that I don't have access to gcc.

Is there a way to activate gcc from inside the virtualenv? If not, is there any other library that works with PostgreSQL that does not use gcc?

My attempt to install psycopg2 at A2hosting.com gives me this error:

```
running install
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.4
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.4/psycopg2
copying lib/errorcodes.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.4/psycopg2
copying lib/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.4/psycopg2
copying lib/extensions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.4/psycopg2
copying lib/pool.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.4/psycopg2
copying lib/tz.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.4/psycopg2
copying lib/psycopg1.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.4/psycopg2
copying lib/extras.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.4/psycopg2
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.4/psycopg2/tests
copying tests/types_extras.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.4/psycopg2/tests
copying tests/types_basic.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.4/psycopg2/tests
copying tests/test_psycopg2_dbapi20.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.4/psycopg2/tests
copying tests/test_dates.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.4/psycopg2/tests
copying tests/bugX000.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.4/psycopg2/tests
copying tests/test_copy.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.4/psycopg2/tests
copying tests/test_async.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.4/psycopg2/tests
copying tests/test_notify.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.4/psycopg2/tests
copying tests/extras_dictcursor.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.4/psycopg2/tests
copying tests/test_lobject.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.4/psycopg2/tests
copying tests/test_connection.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.4/psycopg2/tests
copying tests/test_green.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.4/psycopg2/tests
copying tests/bug_gc.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.4/psycopg2/tests
copying tests/dbapi20_tpc.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.4/psycopg2/tests
copying tests/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.4/psycopg2/tests
copying tests/test_quote.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.4/psycopg2/tests
copying tests/testutils.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.4/psycopg2/tests
copying tests/dbapi20.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.4/psycopg2/tests
copying tests/test_cursor.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.4/psycopg2/tests
copying tests/test_cancel.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.4/psycopg2/tests
copying tests/test_transaction.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.4/psycopg2/tests
copying tests/testconfig.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.4/psycopg2/tests
running build_ext
building 'psycopg2._psycopg' extension
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.4
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.4/psycopg
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.4 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x080309 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/usr/include/python2.4 -I. -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/pgsql/server -c psycopg/psycopgmodule.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.4/psycopg/psycopgmodule.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
unable to execute gcc: Permission denied
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

UPDATE:

I've discovered that the machine on which I'm trying to install psycopg2 doesn't have PostgreSQL. The webhosting company has PostgreSQL installed on another server. What can be done in a situation like this?

Comment: I have the same problem now with this very hosting. Have you managed to install psycopg2 eventually? If so, please share how you did that.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need PostgreSQL, you need the PostgreSQL client libraries and development files. You can try asking the host to install them, or failing that you can build it on a similar platform and copy the package manually.

Comment: The environment have Red Hat installed. Can I build it in a Ubuntu? What setting I need to change in the Psycopg2 when I copy/paste the package? Best Regards,